# Spring ManyToMany cascade error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas con `@ManyToMany` pero no me crea la relación correctamente y no sé por qué ya que le especifico que hacer en caso de `Cascade`. Estoy utilizando una base de datos PostgreSQL.

Una parte de la relación es:

```
@JoinTable(name = "aditivo_alerta",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_alerta", referencedColumnName = "id")},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_aditivo", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Aditivo> aditivosAlerta;
```

Y la otra es:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "aditivosAlerta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Alerta> alertasAditivos;
```

Al crearme la relación en consola aparece:

```
Hibernate: alter table aditivo_alerta add constraint FKlqa4tqvs3wui78d5p3tioto3h foreign key (id_aditivo) references aditivo
Hibernate: alter table aditivo_alerta add constraint FKm8ol7pkini1p00vbtfv39j0m foreign key (id_alerta) references alerta
```

Así que no está tomando la acción para cascade. Además, si miro el estado de la base de datos lo compruebo y no se ha creado la relación correctamente:

[image: Base de datos vista en Toad Edge]

El código que genera spring para la llave externa es:

```
ALTER TABLE public.aditivo_alerta
   ADD CONSTRAINT fklqa4tqvs3wui78d5p3tioto3h FOREIGN KEY
          (id_aditivo)
          REFERENCES public.aditivo (id)
             MATCH SIMPLE
             ON DELETE NO ACTION
             ON UPDATE NO ACTION
          NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
```

Así que efectivamente no está cogiendo el `CascadeType.ALL`. He probado varias opcciones de `CascadeType` y nada.

¿Se supone que tal como está Spring debería crear la relación correctamente no?

Answer (score 0):

`CascadeType` no se relaciona con el "on xxxx cascade " de la `foreign key` en la base de datos, se relaciona con las entidades manejadas por el `EntityManager`. De hecho `CascadeType` tiene `Attach` `Detach` `Persist` que no existen en sql.

En la relación hay dos partes: la que maneja la relación y la parte manejada. El `CascadeType` le indica a la que parte que maneja la relación (`Alerta` en tu caso) que debe hacer respecto a la manejada (`Aditivo`).

Esto último también implica que el uso de `CascadeType` tiene sentido si se usa en la parte que maneja la relación unicamente. No se si del otro lado tiene algún efecto.

Revisé la [documentación de hybernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade-on-delete) y lo único que encontré que afecta al "On Delete" de la foreign key es el annotation @OnDelete. (No vi nada para "on update")

```
Ej:
@OnDelete( action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE )
```